# Виснет БД при любом сохранении

Tags: mysql, magento

Есть сайт на magento 1.9, более 500к товаров. В последнее время любое первое сохранение в БД (insert или update) приводит к зависанию сайта от 15 минут до часа.Последующие сохранения проходят быстро. В БД есть таблицы InnoDB и MyISAM. Индексация, очистка кеша не помогает. Во время зависания сервер не перегружен.

Comment: Вы используете прямые запросы к базе данных ? Или все таки используете zend?

Comment: zend. Проблема уже устранена. Причина была в настройках mysql. Отключила query_cache и зависания исчезли.